# Erlang: why is my process still running after unregistering process ID?

Tags: erlang, server

Even though I unregister `sts`, my spawned process is not stopped. How can I stop it not using gen_server?

```
start() ->
  case whereis(sts) of
    undefined ->
      PidA = spawn(dist_erlang, init,[]),
      register(sts, PidA),
      {ok,PidA};
    _ ->
      {ok,whereis(sts)}
  end.

stop() ->
   case whereis(sts) of
     undefined -> 
        already_stopped;
     _ ->
        unregister(sts),
        stopped,
  end.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using unregister does not stop the process. Stopping the process does, however, unregister it. So instead of using unregister here, use `erlang:exit/2`

```
stop() ->
    case whereis(sts) of
        undefined -> 
            already_stopped;
        Pid -> 
            exit(Pid, normal), % Use whatever exit reason you want
            stopped
     end.
```

All that being said, you should really be using the OTP process behaviours (like gen_server), as they make process management much easier. With an OTP process, you can instead `call` the process and tell it to stop, so that when you get your reply it has already stopped. Otherwise your exit message may take some time to get through.

Answer (score 1):

`unregister` does not stop the process.  It just removes binding between process id and given atom.

You need to remember that `stop/0` function is run in context of process that called this function, and not the gen_server itself.  Actually (almost) only way to interact with some process is to send it a message.  So you could implement your `stop/0` function like this:

```
%% send stop message to `sts` server
stop() ->
  gen_server:cast(sts, stop). 

%% [...]


handle_cast( OtherCastMessages, State) -> 
  %% handel other cast messages ;
  %% [...] ;

%% handle stop message
handle_cast( _Message = stop, State) ->
  {stop, 
   _Reason = normal, 
   State}. % return result that stops server


%% [...]

terminate(_Reason = normal, State) ->
   %% could do some cleanup in this callback
   ok.
```

So to stop server you have to return special tuple from one of the behaviour functions.  You can read more about this [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#Module:init-1).  And of course trigger one of behaviour functions, you have to send message to your server with `gen_server:cast` or `gen_server:call` (or just send a message and handle it with `handle_info`).  What to use is your decision.  Finally `terminate2` is called (no matter which callback returned tuple with `stop` atom), where you could do some cleanup with your state.

Of course you could unregister your process in `terminate` callback, but when process dies the unregistration is handled automatically.

Comment: this is a school assignment and I am not allowed to use gen_server's at all.